# Enumerate files *.pdf exclude *_book.pdf

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, ls

How can enumerate all file file in dir, exclude by pattern.

For example: all *.pdf exclude *_book.pdf. I try so:

```
for $PDF in $(ls *.pdf | grep -v *_book.pdf);
do
   echo "File $PDF"
done
```

It is a good way? Are there any other ways? Used **if** statement or other.

Comment: This is what I wrote here in error "for $PDF" in the original I had "for PDF"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Also, the variable that you declare in the `for` loop should not have a dollar sign. The dollar sign *interpolates* the value of a variable; so `$PDF` reads as "the current value of the variable whose name is `PDF`".

```
for PDF in *.pdf
do
    case $PDF in
     *_book.pdf) continue;;
    esac
    echo "File $PDF"
done
```

The `case` syntax scares some beginners, but I vastly prefer it over `if` for things like this.  But if you prefer, you can use

```
    if [[ $PDF =~ _book\.pdf$ ]]; then
        continue
    fi
```

or the shorthand

```
    [[ $PDF =~ _book\.pdf$ ]] && continue
```

`case` has the additional benefit that it is portable to POSIX `sh` and even the good olde original Bourne `sh`.

Notice that the pattern in `case` is a glob, while `[[ $variable =~ regex ]]` uses a regular expression (so there should be no `*` before `_book`).

Answer (score 2):

Using `shopt -s extglob` (which could be a default on your system, otherwise set it), you can use extended matching and this includes negative match patterns:

```
# Directry contents
>ls -1
1_book_not.pdf
1_book.pdf
1.pdf
1.txt

# With negative match
>ls -1 !(*_book).pdf
1_book_not.pdf
1.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a slight syntax error in your `for` expression. Try the following instead:

```
for PDF in $(ls *.pdf | grep -v *_book.pdf);
do
   echo "File $PDF"
done
```

This seems to work good.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' ! -name '*_book.pdf'
```

For example, consider a directory with these four files:

```
$ ls
a_book.pdf  book.txt  nook.pdf  not_book1.pdf
```

Now, run our command:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' ! -name '*_book.pdf'
./not_book1.pdf
./nook.pdf
```

#### How it works

- `find .` tells find to start a search in the current directory.
- `-maxdepth 1` tells find to skip subdirectories.
- `-name '*.pdf'` tells find to look for files whose names end if `.pdf`.
- `! -name '*_book.pdf'` tells finds to exclude from the output any file whose name ends with `_book.pdf`.